# jQuery If is set, or if is not null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery Code:

```
$("#menu span").click(function() {
    var url = this.getAttribute("data-url");
    var mobile = this.getAttribute("data-mobile");
    var facebook = this.getAttribute("data-facebook");

    if (url) {

    }

    if (mobile) {

    }

    if (facebook) {

    }

};
```

But it is a little glitchy.  Is there an alternative I can use to see if this data attribute exists?  Instead of using `if (url) { }`

My HTML will be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><span data-mobile="1" data-url="http://url.com">Site #1</span></li>
    <li><span data-url="http://site2.com" data-facebook="http://fblink">Site #2</span></li>
    <li><span data-url="http://site3.com">Site #3</span></li>
</ul>
```

So not everyone will have all of the data attributes.

---

**Edit:** How do I clear everything once the span is clicked again?

For example:

```
if (data.mobile) {

    $(".mobile").attr("data-link", data.mobile);
    $(".mobile").attr('class', 'icon mobile on');

}
```

So by default, the class is loaded with `icon mobile off`.  Then when the span is clicked, it runs through the functions, and if it has mobile assigned to it, then it will turn the class to `icon mobile on` which is perfect for the first view.  But then when I go to another span and it does not have a mobile, it still stays ON from before. How can I clear stuff like that on each new click?

```
<div class="icons">
    <div class="icon website off" data-link=""></div>
    <div class="icon mobile off" data-link=""></div>
    <div class="icon fb off" data-link=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `data` attributes you can use jQuery `data()` method to there values and optimize your code something like this.

```
$("#menu span").click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();//Will get all data attribute as key/value pairs
    if (data.url) {
    }
    if (data.mobile) {
    }
    if (data.facebook) {
    }
};
```

If there are multiple `span` the you can use `delegate` on the `#menu` and look for `span`, this way the `click` handler will be attached only once on `#menu` element. Try this.

```
$("#menu").delegate('span', 'click', function() {
    var data = $(this).data();//Will get all data attribute as key/value pairs
    if (data.url) {
    }
    if (data.mobile) {
    }
    if (data.facebook) {
    }
};
```

Update based on OP's comment:

```
if (data.mobile) {
    $('.icons').attr("data-link", data.mobile)
    .removeClass('off').addClass('on');
}
else{
    $('.icons').removeAttr("data-link")
    .removeClass('on').addClass('off');
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I learned something new, thank you. I  made one last edit to the question if you don't mind!

Comment: I can't get it to work :( I updated once again with the HTML I am using.  The icon mobile off is in a new div.

Comment: Where is that div in the page? Is it for every `span`?

Comment: No it is just shown once on the page.  It is 3 icons, using CSS - and if it is set to off, then the background becomes less noticable, and when it is set to on it is bright and active.  so every time a span is clicked and it has the data-mobile attribute, then that mobile icon should light up and get set to ON.  when I go to another one, it should reset back to off, then check to see if data-mobile exists and either set to on or off. does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
var $spanObj = $("#menu span[data-url]").click(function() {
    var url = this.getAttribute("data-url");
    var mobile = this.getAttribute("data-mobile");
    var facebook = this.getAttribute("data-facebook");
    ...
    if (data.mobile) {
        $spanObj.filter('[data-mobile]').attr('class','icon mobile off');
        $(".mobile").attr("data-link", data.mobile);
        $(".mobile").attr('class', 'icon mobile on');

    }
});
```

Only select spans that contain the data-url attribute to begin with.

Comment: Hi, please see edit.  I left out the rest.  I need to be able to use it for all three.

Comment: Ah, ok. I would go with your current multiple if statement setup. As far as i can tell, it would be the most efficient, the only alternative is using .filter to filter to only spans that have atleast one of those data-attributes, but you will still need the if statements.

Comment: Or, you could use a separate click event for each case.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much.  I made one more edit with another question if you don't mind!